# Could angularjs map a model into a "virtual model" with a filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

there's two model I put into Angular js

```
// full device list
$scope.devices = [{id:1, on:true}, {id:2, on:false}, {id:3, on:true}];
// devices with on == true
$scope.devicesOn = $scope.devices.filter(function(t){return t.on==true});
```

in page:

```
<span>the following {{ devicesOn.length }} of {{ devices.length }} are on</span>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='device in devicesOn'>{{device.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

so the model `devices` is dynamic. However `devicesOn` isn't dynamic because it is not lazy evaluation.

I know you can write something like `$scope.countOnDevices = function(){return ...}` but it's not ideal. Any more elegant way to solve this?

It's like creating a `view` (applied with a `where` filter) from existing `table` in a RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a watcher to watch on the change of the devices list, the logic can be fired when there is any change to the list

```
$scope.$watch('devices', function () {
    $scope.devicesOn = $scope.devices.filter(function (t) {
        return t.on == true
    });
}, true)
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EW6Hu/)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, I forgot to mention that `devicesOn` need to be displayed in `<li>` list. Anyway, basically I need to watch the `devices` model and create a new `devicesOn` everytime?

Answer (score 0):

@sza's answer works great, I also found another solution from here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/3LyIjNroT5c

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/7WY_BmFzd3U/Zd_jHnMu58YJ

```
ng-repeat='item in filtered = (items | filter:filterExpr)
```

then simply use `{{filtered.length}}`

demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/Nk8qy/2/)